# How to rollback data changes in DBContext if 'SubmitChanges' failed but other submits are required?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, transactions

In some business cases my app I have error cause inside of transaction. Situation looks like this:

```
static void MyFunc(DBContext context)
{
    context.MyObjects.InsertOnSubmit(new MyObj{Id=1});
                                         // Id - is a primary key
    context.MyObjects.InsertOnSubmit(new MyObj{Id=1});
                                         // here I force system to fail
                                         // by trying to add record with
                                         // duplicated primary key value

    context.SubmitChanges(); // causes an error (as expected)
}

static void main()
{
    using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
    {
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope scope = CreateTransactionScope())
            {
                MyFunc(context);

                scope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            MyLog log = new MyLog{...valid object data... want to log error ... };
            context.MyLogs.InsertOnSubmit(log);
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

the problem here is that attempt to save 'log' object causes attempt to save previously added objects into 'MyObject' table too! And as a result I can't save log record... and my 'main' function throws an exception...

How could I resolve that? Any thoughts are welcome.

(I'm using MS SQL 2005, Linq2Sql, .NET 3.5, ideas for .NET 4.0 are also welcome!)

P.S. I know it could be a good idea to call 'scope.Rollback', but if I leave 'using (TransactionScope scope ...)' without calling 'Complete' then 'Rollback should be applied automatically...

P.P.S. I could create a new 'DBContext' object, but don't think it is reasonable.

Comment: why is creating separate context not a reasonable solution?

Comment: If there are any other way - I would prefer that... otherwise - yes, it will be a solution... The problem is: I expect in future other cases when my business logic could cause errors during SubmitChanges but still other changes in the same call (in the same context) will be required to be done... and playing with context doesn't looks very attractive for me.

Comment: if you want some data to be written even if the rest fails you have two simple choices: 1) use a separate context, 2) use separate transactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A transaction is a tool to group actions that must be performed as a whole, not in parts. Since you have some actions that can (and in your case must) be easily separated from the rest, it seems a lot more appropriate to use two separate transactions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the DataContext will keep a reference to all the objects that were loaded from or attached to it in memory.  I could be wrong, but I do not believe the changes within the TransactionScope are rolled back in the "in-memory" objects.

Therefore SubmitChanges() on the context in the error handler will try to resubmit all the changes to the "in-memory" model.  The only way I know of to correct this is to reset the "in-memory" model by creating a new context.

Answer (score 1):

you can rollback in context like this

```
public void Rollback()
{
    base.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList().ForEach(entry => entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged);
}
```

Comment: But this won't true-up the in-memory object to the current database object, right? If later, in the lifetime of the DbContext and that object, you modified another property on it, then since other properties remain dirty they could also get saved back to the database (depending on your detect changes settings).

Comment: That's not a rollback, it merely prevents changes from being persisted